# I need my Django get_absolute_url to do two different things

Tags: python, html, django

So I have a small issue with one of my models when I want to fire `get_absolute_url`.

When someone create's an article on my site I would like it to return them to the 'under-review' page to tell them that there page is currently under review. But the  issue is that my sitemap is showing that every article comes up as `www.example.com/under-review/` instead of `www.example.com/post/example-slug`

I would normally use `return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})` for that which fixes the problem. But then brings up the issue that when someone creates the article, it takes them straight to the page instead of the `under-review` page.

Model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
        return reverse('under-review')
```

Ideally I would have it so when someone posts a post, it takes them to the `under-review` page up at the same time serves the `return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})` so it shows up correctly in my sitemap.

Thanks.

Comment: The absolute URL shouldn't change for a resource. It should always remain the same. What that URL returns can change though. In your `post-detail` view you can check to see if the article has been reviewed. If it has return the article, if it has not you can display the under-review content.

Comment: @JohnKeyes Ah that sounds exactly what I need. Would you be able to post an answer to this question showing me an example on how I would do this, as I am a little lost on how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here but it should be enough to steer you in the correct direction. The following is some pseudo code, you can adapt as you need.

Let's say you have an `Article` model like:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    is_reviewed = models.BooleanField()
```

Then your `post-detail` view can check this field:

```
def get_post_detail(request, article_id):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    if post.is_reviewed:
        return render(request, 'myapp/article.html', {'article': article}) 
    return render(request, 'myapp/under_review.html', {'article': article})
```